# Method to realize any function with 2 input NAND/NOR gate

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, nand

I'm preparing for a competitive exam where often these type of questions are asked

> Find the minimum number of 2 input NAND gates required to implement the function F(A, B, C, D) = AB + ACD + BC’ where literals and their complements are available

And I often end up with a non minimal realization. Though I think there can be some pattern behind such type of questions.

Is there a method to implement any given function with only 2[or n] input NAND gate?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of Karnaugh Maps and bubble pushing? I am quite sure you can use a K-Map in order to find the minimal SOP / POS expression, then use bubble pushing in order to implement the minimal expression with NOR / NAND gates. Try to look into those concepts, try them, and if you're still stuck, post your work here and @ me, I might be able to help.

Comment: I am familiar with K Maps, though bubble pushing I don't know of. My specific requirement was to realize the circuit with gates of fan-in value of 2. I'll check on bubble pushing and post here.

Comment: Here's a [helpful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdKF_4DiBE8) regarding the subject. Please, follow the steps that I have mentioned in my first comment, edit your post to show what you've tried (the K-map you've drawn, and the initial schematic of the implementation of the boolean function) and notify me if necessary. Cheers!